# Linux route/IPtables with internal VM network

Tags: linux, routing, iptables

I am having some trouble figuring this all out. I have

```
Windows 7 
[10.10.30.1] 

ROUTER
[eth0=192.168.4.134 eth1=10.10.30.254] 

Ubuntu 
[192.168.4.143]
```

I can ping eth0 and eth1 from Win7, and also 192.168.4.143. I can ping Win7 from the two router interfaces too. My Win7 box traceroutes from 10.10.30.254 to 192.168.4.143. I can access the internet on Win7 and the Ubuntu box, so that's all correct

BUT! Ubuntu can't connect to the Win7 machine.

When I traceroute to the Win7 box, a packet gets to 192.168.4.2 but goes no further. I have no idea where/what 192.168.4.2 is.

so somewhere 192.168.4.2 and eth0/eth1 are not forwarding packets between each other. I'm really struggling here!

I am on VMware Fusion.

My route -n for the router VM is:

```
Destination Gateway     Genmask       Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0     192.168.4.2 0.0.0.0       UG 0 0 0             eth0
10.10.30.0  0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0 U                    eth1
192.168.4.0 0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0 U 1 0 0              eth0
```

If anyone can help, that'll be great.

Thanks

Comment: What's the routing table on the Ubuntu machine? As for "I have no idea where/what 192.168.4.2 is" - it's your default gateway on the router, probably your internet router or similar.